# Password protect OneDrive folder link

Tags: api, onedrive

Does anyone have experience using the OneDrive api?

I want to be able to create a password protected link to a folder in my OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph api. The api seems to have a CreateLink action that can create a link but it doesn't seem to document that I can include a password when it is created.

Does anyone know if you can create password protected links via the Microsoft Graph api?

I've include the URL to the documentation I am looking at.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Many thanks in advance.

Rhyd.

Answer (score 0):

It's exposed on the `beta` endpoint but not yet on `v1.0`. Check out the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permission?view=graph-rest-beta

Hopefully it'll be pushed to `v1.0` soon.

**Update 2019-07-12**
The documentation for `createLink` appears to be lacking in beta with respect to password support. A request like the following *should* work though:

```
POST /me/drive/items/{itemId}/createLink
Content-type: application/json

{
  "type": "view",
  "scope": "anonymous",
  "password": "itsasecret"
}
```

Comment: Brad. Thanks for this, but this looks like the JSON that is returned giving info about a link. I need to be able to create a link with a password. The documentation details the createLink endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). This I assume is used to create the link. But there is no details about providing a password in the Request sent? Rhyd

Comment: The docs for createLink in beta are lacking - I've updated my answer and will track fixing them

Comment: Hi Brad,

I get the following Response JSON...

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": "The parameter password does not exist in method createLink.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a15e2bd5-a35e-4c2e-ae1c-a53c80a68693",
            "date": "2019-07-15T14:22:36"
        }
    }
}`

This was using the endpoint...

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/{itemId}/createLink

Any ideas?

Have Microsoft really not provided documentation for the beta endpoint?

Comment: Ah you're using OneDrive for Business... passwords are currently only supported on OneDrive Personal. Here's the documentation change I'm pushing to fix `createLink`: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/5114